# Package Acceptance Validation Errors on Visual Assets

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-store-apps, windows-store, appxmanifest

I'm getting the following error when I upload a windows app package the developer console:

Package acceptance validation error: The following image(s) specified in the appxManifest.xml of xxxx_x86.appx were not found: Assets\Branding\StoreLogo.png, Assets\Branding\SmallLogo.png, Assets\Branding\Logo.png, Assets\Branding\Splash.png

The appxmanifest designer looks like this:

[image]

This is the contents of my Assets\Branding directory:

[image]

Obviously, splash.png does not exist here.  If I copy splash.scale-100.png and call it splash.png, and then simply include it in the project, this happens to me:
[image]
[image]

Notice that Splash.scale-100.png still exists.  If I try use the "..." button to add splash.scale-100.png to the scaled image box there, it deletes the newly added splash.png.  What the heck man!

How do I appease the appx package validation gods?  These screenshots come from visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue with the *.scale-xxx images not being set as Content, Copy if newer.  They weren't ending up in the appx file.